# Main.class.getResource() and jTextArea

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea, getresource

When I read a file from the jar file and want to put it in in a jTextArea, it shows me crypted symbols, not the true content.

What I am doing:

```
public File loadReadme() {
    URL url = Main.class.getResource("/readme.txt");
    File file = null;

    try {
        JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        file = new File(connection.getJarFileURL().toURI());

        if (file.exists()) {
            this.readme = file;
            System.out.println("all ok!");

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("not ok");
    }

    return file;
}
```

And then i read the file:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFileToArray(File file) {
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String test = sCurrentLine;
            array.add(test);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("not diese!");

    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Now, i put all lines from the ArrayList in the jTextArea, that showes me things like that:

PK����?����^��S?��3���  z_��
%�Q Tl?7��+�;�
�fK�    �N��:k�����]�Xk,������U"�����q��\����%�Q#4x�|[���o� S{��:�aG�*s g�'.}���n�X����5��q���hpu�H���W�9���h2��Q����#���@7(�@����F!��~��?����j�?\xA�/�Rr.�v�l�PK�bv�=

The textfiled contains:

```
SELECTION:
----------
By clicking the CTRL Key and the left mouse button you go in the selection mode.
Now, by moving the mouse, you paint a rectangle on the map.

DOWNLOAD:
---------
By clicking on the download button, you start the download.
The default location for the tiles to download is: <your home>
```

I am sure that the file exists! 
Does anyone know what the problem is? Is my "getResource" correct?

Comment: What does your readme.txt contain? In other words, what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: Update your question with this, i think it may be useful

Comment: did it! sorry, I am a beginner ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output, I'm suspecting your code actually reads the JAR file itself (since it starts with `PK`). Why not use the following code to read the text file:

```
Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/readme.txt")
```

That would give you an `InputStream` to the text file without doing the hassle of opening the JAR file, etc.

You can then pass the `InputStream` object to the `readFileToArray` method (instead of the `File` object) and use

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

The rest of your code should not need any change.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment... :(

Comment: how can i read the file know? I think the file is the jar file for the moment!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an **encoding** problem. `FileReader` doesn't allow you to specify that. Try using

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), yourEncoding));
```

Comment: thanks you for that, I am using Linux and my file is named "readme.txt", do you know the encoding of this file?

Comment: I cannot tell the encoding of the file as such. Only the creator of the file can tell that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making far too much work for yourself here.  You start by calling `getResource`, which gives you a URL to the `readme.txt` entry inside your JAR file, but then you take that URL, determine the JAR file that it is pointing inside, then open that JAR file with a `FileInputStream` and read the whole JAR file.

You can instead simply call `.openStream()` on the original URL that `getResource` returned, and this will give you an `InputStream` from which you can read the content of `readme.txt`

```
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

(if `readme.txt` is not encoded in UTF-8 then change that parameter as appropriate)